# MySQL: Facing challenge while getting top N rows for each group

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried all the methods from [This Link](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), and other similar answers from google, but none worked.

I want get first N rows for each `categoryId`

Following is Table format:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| id                    | categoryId        |  title                |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 16181504-00000000079  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 2   |
| 16181504-00000000064  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 3   |
| 16181504-00000000027  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 4   |
| 16181504-00000000065  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 5   |
| 16181504-00000000096  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 6   |
| 16181504-00000000028  |   1603012000000   |   category-2 prod 7   |
| 16181504-00000000536  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 1   |
| 16181504-00000000508  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 2   |
| 16181504-00000000512  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 3   |
| 16181504-00000000511  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 4   |
| 16181504-00000000509  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 5   |
| 16181504-00000000510  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 6   |
| 16181504-00000000538  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 7   |
| 16181504-00000000540  |   1603012000004   |   category-3 prod 8   |
| 16181504-00000000915  |   1603012000005   |   category-5 prod 1   |
| 16181504-00000000913  |   1603012000005   |   category-5 prod 2   |
| 16181504-00000000914  |   1603012000005   |   category-5 prod 3   |
| 16181504-00000001148  |   1603012000006   |   category-1 prod 1   |
| 16181504-00000001146  |   1603012000006   |   category-1 prod 2   |
| 16181504-00000001147  |   1603012000006   |   category-1 prod 3   |
| 16181504-00000001922  |   1603012000009   |   category-4 prod 1   |
| 16181504-00000001924  |   1603012000009   |   category-4 prod 2   |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

"Groupwise max" is a challenging task.  I have studied that and compiled a list of the 'best' (and some not-so-good) ways:

[*groupwise max*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) -- Skip down to "Top-N in each group"; there are two solutions there.  Which applies?  It depends on whether you can have dups.

Some day, I'll add code that makes use of MariaDB's 10.2 "Windowing functions".

Comment: It's not "max".  I just gave few columns, but actual table has many columns.  I may get top N records based on `modified_on` or `brandName` or `price` for each `categoryId`.

Comment: "Max" is the degenerate case; it has simpler techniques.  "Top N" is discussed there, too.  My example also shows only one 'other' column; any number of columns can be handled.